# Coupon for specific product not for subtotal of cart

Tags: product, discount, coupon-codes

I would like to setup a promotion in my Magento system, I not sure defualt magento can do this,

Anyway here is the task:

I have Three products in cart
•Product A: $50
•Product B: $100
•Product C: $70

And I have 10% off coupon code, this coupon is applicable only for price of "Product B" not for subtotal of "Product A", "Product B" and "Product C".

If I am following default Magento "Shopping Cart Price rule"  discount will be $22(50+100+70*10/100) so GrandTotal is $198(50+100+70-22).

But I need discount $10(100*10/100) so GrandTotal is $210(50+100+70-10)
Please help me on this, suggest me to a module which can do this.

*I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2*

Thanks!

Comment: Your coupon code is only for this product or you have several products apply this?

Comment: I have to add this coupon for sevral products! may be "•Product D" and "• Product E" also, but how to handle other products?(Product A and Product C) :(

Comment: i answered to this question,Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to create Coupon Code for any particular product:-

**SKU BASED COUPON CODE**

- Login to Admin
- Go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules
- Click Add New Rule
- Fill Rule Information

**Give conditions**

- On left sidebar, click Conditions tab
- Click **+** icon
- Select Product attribute combination
- Click **+** icon
- Select SKU
- Now, you will see SKU is
- Add your product SKU over there

Note that the SKU option may not show up by default.(Go to: `catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes`. Then search for the ‘SKU’ attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ to YES and re-index if needed.)

**Set Actions**

- You can set how much discount you want to give from here
- Save Rule

Find below image for sku condition
[image]